# Generic type unions convert arguments to never

Tags: typescript

The following code generates the following TS error :

> Argument of type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

```
interface BaseAttribute <Value> {
  value: Value
  validate: (newValue: Value) => boolean
}

type StringAttribute = BaseAttribute<string> & { type: 'string' }

type BoolAttribute = BaseAttribute<boolean> & { type: 'bool' }

type Attribute = StringAttribute | BoolAttribute


const getAttribute = () : Attribute => {
  /* could return any kind of attribute, bool example there */
  return {
    type: 'bool',
    value: true,
    validate: (newBool: boolean) => !!newBool
  }
}

const attribute = getAttribute()
attribute.validate(attribute.value)
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> error
```

I understand that TS doesn't know that the `attribute.value` argument passed comes from the same `attribute`, but is there any way to make it work ?

[Click here for the TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QIJjFYAIwFdJkAeANTgBtiIA+ZAbwChlkA3W+gLmWp0I7LrWAATOJH4AKEBADugvgJ4QAlMgC8TQgHs9NCHBCsAvq1ZgAngAcUAZXygA5rmckyWtJhx4CnhDkGM4gLkwAZCzINvb8AOQhBGHxyBZWdiioBjTuAaQo3uhYeUQF5PqGxiCR0bEQCZU0qen1yKWB2shOyW7+ZWQAPmg5HQWWrAh6ICHILhBgY17IMpr8S4VMbBwA9ABUyFPENOLIUAvEUCDIJtbIANagp3owN-2BADTITcgQAB5wAC2tiMMQAFtAUHsdiJzmBLtdthwYplGjl4h8RBxuEJ+Ph6JjkaIaBIpA0VvIFNlDPwmtVNDpkABCJmU6k0EQWdJTGZgN4eApdeaLd4FVasKQCyAAOhxpMgMkl+RlOPo6iAA)

Comment: TS cannot natively support *correlated unions* as discussed in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The recommended approach is a refactoring to a particular generic form as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I perform that refactoring here I get [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Wzqx4m). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yes, its perfect @jcalz, you can write up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're run into TypeScript's lack of direct support for *correlated unions* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). As you said, `attribute.validate(attribute.value)` doesn't work because TypeScript doesn't track the *identity* of `attribute` here, just its *type*. So it checks the code as if you wrote `attribute1.validate(attribute2.validate)`,  and since `Attribute` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), it can't be sure that you're not passing an argument from one union member to a function from a different union member.  It's essentially impossible to directly call a union of functions with a union of arguments in TypeScript without the compiler complaining.

The recommended approach in situations like this is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and involved refactoring to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to unions, instead of unions themselves.  The idea is to come up with a "base" object type representing the part of the structure that changes with each union member, and then represent your operations in terms of [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that base type or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that base type. The goal is that `attribute.validate()` will be seen as a single function type whose parameter is exactly the type of `attribute.value`.

Here's how the refactoring might look for your example. The base object type is

```
interface AttributeMap {
  string: string,
  bool: boolean;
}
```

and then your `Attribute` type can be represented as a generic index into a mapped type over `AttributeMap`:

```
type Attribute<K extends keyof AttributeMap = keyof AttributeMap> =
  { [P in K]: BaseAttribute<AttributeMap[P]> & { type: P } }[K]
```

A type of the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` is called a *distributive object type* because it turns unions in `K` into unions in `F<K>`. I mean, if `K` is `K1 | K2 | K3` then `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]` is `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`.  So `Attribute<keyof AttributeMap>` is equivalent to your original `Attribute` type.  And since there's a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `keyof AttributeMap`, that means when you mention the type `Attribute` without a type argument, you get a type equivalent to your original `Attribute` (allowing us to leave some of your original code the same).

But now since `Attribute` is generic, you can write `Attribute<"string">` to recover `StringAttribute` and `Attribute<"bool">` to recover `BoolAttribute`.  And when we use a generic type argument `K`, then `Attribute<K>` will be seen as something with a non-union `validate` property and a non-union `value` property.

You still can't just write `attribute.validate(attribute.value)` when `attribute` is of type `Attribute`. But you *can* do it when it's of type `Attribute<K>` for generic `K`. That means we should wrap that code in a generic function:

```
function validateAttribute<K extends keyof AttributeMap>(attribute: Attribute<K>) {
  attribute.validate(attribute.value); // okay
}
```

And now, finally, you can call that function on your union-typed `attribute`:

```
const attribute = getAttribute();
validateAttribute(attribute);
```

---

So, there you go. Note that the approach in microsoft/TypeScript#47109 isn't 100% type safe, there are still potential issues whereby you could end up tricking the compiler into allowing actually unsafe code; see [microsoft/TypeScript#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730). But it's definitely a lot safer to do it this way, rather than taking your original code and just using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress errors.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1):

#### Preface:

This is an interesting question! I would also have been confused by such behavior!

As to the **why**, unfortunately I cannot offer you an in-depth technical explanation of this behavior, sorry (but I would love to know why this is happening!).

---

#### *Potential* Work-around

You could use `type guards` to `narrow` the type of your `attribute` returned by `getAttribute()` (See the TS Handbook: [`Narrowing`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html))

e.g. in your example:

```js
// Original: 1 LOC
attribute.validate(attribute.value)
//                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> Error!

// Updated: 5 LOC (7+ LOC if there are additional `Attribute` variants)
if (attribute.type === 'string') {
  attribute.validate(attribute.value)
} else if (attribute.type === 'bool'){
  attribute.validate(attribute.value)
} else {
  // Not possible as written
  // BUT there could be more attribute types possible
}
```